# How to check whether odd lane is in a given range when its previous even lane equals to some value using SIMD?

Tags: x86, simd, sse

This question is an extension of [How to check if even/odd lanes are in given ranges using SIMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76174659/how-to-check-if-even-odd-lanes-are-in-given-ranges-using-simd).

Given a `__m128i` which stores 16 chars, the even-index lane refers to even lane (i.e., lanes at 0, 2, 4, ..., 14), and odd-index lane refers to odd lane (i.e, lanes at 1, 3, 5, ... 15). In my application, each group is disjoint, consisting of two adjacent lanes, and thus there are 8 groups.

In my application, there are some extra restrictions (known at compiling time) on every group. To be specific, if the even lane equals to some value (e.g., `a`), then the next odd lane should be in a given range (e.g., `[b, c]`); otherwise, the next odd lane can be arbitrary.

Suppose there are two restrictions:

- 2, [1, 5]
- 3, [4, 6]

```
# valid
vec = [2, 4, 3, 5, 1, 10, ...]

# invalid, because when 0-th (even) is 2, 6 is not in range of [1, 5]
vec = [2, 6, 3, 5, 1, 10, ...]
```

Any idea how to use SIMD intrinsics to check whether the given `__m128i` satisfies those restrictions?

Comment: If you have multiple restrictions, is there some easy way to compute the range `[b, c]` from `a`? If not, how many different restrictions can you have? (More than 2, more than 16?) Can you influence how your inputs are created, i.e., could you have them non-interleaved without extra operations?

Comment: The pair of `(a, [b, c])` are predefined. In this specific case, there are about 10 restrictions. @chtz

Comment: If you have multiple such conditions, you probably want to combine boolean vectors with SIMD ops like `_mm_and_si128` / `_mm_andnot_si128` / `_mm_or_si128` before one final `_mm_movemask_epi8`, instead of having multiple scalar masks to booleanize and combine.  (Or multiple FLAGS conditions to materialize into integer booleans from `_mm_testz_si128`.)

Comment: If you have some that are any-element-true vs. all-elements-true, note that any-true is the same as all-false, so `andnot` might help in combining them.  If you have some tests on just the odd elements to be checked with `movemask() & 0x5555 == 0x5555`, you might keep those separate.  (Or `movemask() & 0x5555 == 0` is cheaper, can be done with one scalar `test` instruction.)

Comment: Do you want this across multiple vectors, like could it be useful to produce a bitmap from a pair of input `__m128i` vectors, if `_mm_packs_epi16` could be useful in lining up odds with evens?

Comment: These are once again signed ranges?

Comment: If the relevant `a` values are close together (not further than 15 apart), you may want to find the correct min/max-borders using a `pshufb`-lookup. You still leave a lot unclear in your question ...

Answer (score 0):

Here’s one possible implementation. Tested very little.
It requires SSSE3 and SSE 4.1.

```cpp
#include <emmintrin.h>  // SSE2
#include <tmmintrin.h>  // SSSE3
#include <smmintrin.h>  // SSE 4.1
#include <vector>
#include <assert.h>

// Assemble integer from 4 bytes
inline int intFromBytes( uint8_t b0, uint8_t b1, uint8_t b2, uint8_t b3 )
{
    uint32_t res = b0;
    res |= ( (uint32_t)b1 ) << 8;
    res |= ( (uint32_t)b2 ) << 16;
    res |= ( (uint32_t)b3 ) << 24;
    return (int)res;
}

// Pack the range into a single integer
// Bytes 0 and 1 are group key, same value in both bytes
// Byte 2 is minimum of the range
// Byte 3 is ( 0xFF - ( maximum of the range ) )
inline int makeRangeEntry( uint8_t k, uint8_t first, uint8_t last )
{
    assert( first <= last );
    return intFromBytes( k, k, first, 0xFF - last );
}

// Duplicate even-indexed bytes
inline __m128i moveldup_epi8( __m128i vec )
{
    const __m128i perm = _mm_setr_epi8( 0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 10, 10, 12, 12, 14, 14 );
    return _mm_shuffle_epi8( vec, perm );
}

// Create vector with the following bytes:
// vec[1], 255-vec[1], vec[3], 255-vec[3], ..
inline __m128i unpackComparison( __m128i vec )
{
    vec = _mm_srli_epi16( vec, 8 );
    __m128i high = _mm_sub_epi16( _mm_set1_epi16( 0x00FF ), vec );
    high = _mm_slli_epi16( high, 8 );
    return _mm_or_si128( vec, high );
}

// Compare unsigned bytes for a >= b
inline __m128i cmpge_epu8( __m128i a, __m128i b )
{
    __m128i ax = _mm_max_epu8( a, b );
    return _mm_cmpeq_epi8( ax, a );
}

// Duplicate even-indexed int16 lanes
inline __m128i moveldup_epi16( __m128i v )
{
    __m128i shifted = _mm_slli_epi32( v, 16 );
    return _mm_blend_epi16( shifted, v, 0b01010101 );
}

// Duplicate odd-indexed int16 lanes
inline __m128i movehdup_epi16( __m128i v )
{
    __m128i shifted = _mm_srli_epi32( v, 16 );
    return _mm_blend_epi16( shifted, v, 0b10101010 );
}

// Returns true when valid
// Use makeRangeEntry() function to initialize the vector
bool checkRangesSse( __m128i vec, const std::vector<int>& tests )
{
    // Unpack bytes into 2 vectors: keys with duplicate even lanes,
    // and values from odd lanes, duplicated with flipped signs
    const __m128i keys = moveldup_epi8( vec );
    const __m128i vals = unpackComparison( vec );

    __m128i failed = _mm_setzero_si128();

    for( int e : tests )
    {
        // Broadcast the entry, and unpack into 2 vectors
        const __m128i ev = _mm_set1_epi32( e );
        const __m128i entryKey = moveldup_epi16( ev );
        const __m128i entryRange = movehdup_epi16( ev );

        // Compare keys for equality
        const __m128i eq = _mm_cmpeq_epi8( keys, entryKey );
        // Compare values against the range
        // Because we inverted signs with (255-b), one comparison checks both ends of the range
        const __m128i cmp = cmpge_epu8( vals, entryRange );

        // Passed check when keys are different: ( eq == 0 )
        // Passed check when range is good: ( eq == 0xFFFF && cmp == 0xFFFF )
        // The failed check: ( eq == 0xFFFF && cmp != 0xFFFF )
        __m128i res = _mm_xor_si128( eq, cmp );
        res = _mm_and_si128( res, eq );
        failed = _mm_or_si128( failed, res );
    }

    return (bool)_mm_testz_si128( failed, failed );
}
```

**Update:** I’ve just noticed your ranges are known at compile-time.

Ideally, remove the `std::vector` argument from that function, and instead use a global variable of type `const std::array<int, 10>` if you have 10 of these ranges.

Also, if you only have 10 ranges, that array gonna take 40 bytes of memory. If you decorate that array with `alignas(64)` the complete array will be in a single cache line.

Comment: Style note: I'd write `_mm_set1_epi16( 0xFF )` as `_mm_set1_epi16( 0x00FF )`, writing out the whole pattern that repeats, including the leading zeros.  That saves the reader the small amount of mental effort to notice that it's `epi16` and mentally tack on the zeros to see the real pattern.

Comment: @PeterCordes Fixed. Also removed small broadcasts. Without AVX2 they emit too many instructions: `movsx`, `movd`, `punpcklbw`, `punpcklwd`, `pshufd` for a single `_mm_set1_epi8` instrinsic.

Comment: I posted a different answer optimized for repeating the check of the same ranges over different `__m128i` input vectors. (With signed ranges like they were using in their last question).  Even if you rearrange yours to preprocess ranges into vectors outside the loop, I think your accumulation with xor/and/or is slightly more expensive than mine which is just `and (even_match, odd_out_of_range)`/`or`.  Other than that, about the same amount of work.  Can you use `andnot` to combine your checks somehow?

Answer (score 0):

In your previous question, you said you were using the same ranges over multiple `__m128i` inputs.  Assuming that's true again, it's probably best to shuffle pairs of `__m128i` inputs into even vs. odd halves, so from then on we only need vertical SIMD operations.

If we want them in order, `_mm_packus_epi16` is useful (although you have to `_mm_and_si128` both inputs).  Otherwise interleave them:

```c
// split to odds/evens once, reusing these across multiple even_key, odd_range pairs
evens = _mm_blendv_epi8(_mm_slli_epi16(v1, 8), v0, _mm_set1_epi16(0x00ff));
odds  = _mm_blendv_epi8(v1, _mm_srli_epi16(v0, 8), _mm_set1_epi16(0x00ff)); 
...
  tmp = movemask(compare_result);
  tmp & 0x5555  // checks elements from v0
  tmp & 0xaaaa  // checks elements from v1

// Or low/high, costing more setup work
__m128i evenmask = _mm_set1_epi16(0x00ff);
evens = _mm_packus_epi16(_mm_and_si128(v0, evenmask), _mm_and_si128(v1, evenmask));
odds  = _mm_packus_epi16(_mm_srli_epi16(v0, 8),       _mm_srli_epi16(v1, 8));
...
   tmp = movemask(compare_result);
   (uint8_t)tmp  // checks elements from v0, like  cmp al, 0xff to check all-set
   tmp>>8        // checks elements from v1, like  cmp ah, 0xff or test eax, 0xff00
```

If you only have 1 vector, you can use `v1 = v0`.

For the actual conditional range-checking, use the same setup as your previous question:

```c
// loop-invariant constants, set these up once
  __m128i mins =  _mm_set1_epi8( min - 0x80);
  __m128i rangelen = _mm_set1_epi8( max - (min-0x80) );
  __m128i even_key = _mm_set1_epi8( key );


__m128i odds_out_of_range(__m128i evens, __m128i odds, __m128i even_key, __m128i mins, __m128i rangelen)
{
  __m128i vsub = _mm_sub_epi8(odds, mins);
  __m128i odd_outrange = _mm_cmpgt_epi8(vsub, rangelen);
  // or inrange = cmpgt(rangelen, vsub) I think, for an inclusive range?

  __m128i veven_match = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(evens, even_key);
    // bad only if even matched & odd of range
  __m128i bad = _mm_and_si128(veven_match, odd_outrange);
  return bad;
}
```

You might call it from a loop over arrays of range vectors.  With AVX you'd have free broadcast-load of 32-bit elements; with just SSE4.2 you only have free broadcast-loads of 64-bit elements via SSE3 `movddup`.  For simplicity I've just show using full vectors; that lets them work as memory source operands without even needing a separate load instruction.

```c
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct range {
  int8_t even_key, min, max;
};

struct vrange {
  __m128i even_key, mins, rangelen;
};

// static inline
struct vrange make_vrange(struct range r)
{
// preprocessing to go with our range-check
  struct vrange vr;
  vr.mins =  _mm_set1_epi8( r.min - 0x80);
  vr.rangelen = _mm_set1_epi8( r.max - (r.min-0x80) );
  vr.even_key = _mm_set1_epi8( r.even_key );
  return vr;
}

__m128i odds_out_of_range(__m128i evens, __m128i odds, struct vrange vr)
{
  __m128i vsub = _mm_sub_epi8(odds, vr.mins);
  __m128i odd_outrange = _mm_cmpgt_epi8(vsub, vr.rangelen);
  // or inrange = cmpgt(rangelen, vsub) I think, for an inclusive range?

  __m128i veven_match = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(evens, vr.even_key);
    // bad only if even matched & odd of range
  __m128i bad = _mm_and_si128(veven_match, odd_outrange);
  return bad;
}

__m128i check_ranges(__m128i evens, __m128i odds, struct vrange *vranges, int n)
{
    // peel at least the first iteration so some range vectors can stay in registers
    __m128i problems = odds_out_of_range(evens, odds, vranges[0]);
    // maybe peel a total of 2 or 3
    // If necessary, create dummy accept-everything ranges in case n < 3

    for (int i = 1 ; i<n ; i++){
       __m128i bad = odds_out_of_range(evens, odds, vranges[i]);
       problems = _mm_or_si128(problems, bad);  // accumulate across key/range
    }

    return problems;
}

int find_first_out_of_range(const int8_t *p, size_t len, const struct range *scalar_ranges, int nr)
{
    if (nr > 100) return -2;  // assert not too many ranges for a VLA
    struct vrange vranges[nr];
    for (int i = 0 ; i<nr ; i++) {
        vranges[i] = make_vrange(scalar_ranges[i]);
    }
    // perhaps hoist this preprocessing out of this function?

    for (size_t bytepos = 0 ; bytepos<len ; bytepos+=32){
        __m128i v0 = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)&p[bytepos+ 0]);
        __m128i v1 = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)&p[bytepos+16]);

        // split to odds/evens once, reusing these across multiple even_key, odd_range pairs
        __m128i evens = _mm_blendv_epi8(_mm_slli_epi16(v1, 8), v0, _mm_set1_epi16(0x00ff));
        __m128i odds  = _mm_blendv_epi8(v1, _mm_srli_epi16(v0, 8), _mm_set1_epi16(0x00ff));
        __m128i problems = check_ranges(evens, odds, vranges, nr);
        unsigned mask = _mm_movemask_epi8(problems);
        if (mask) {
            if (mask & 0x5555)   // v0
                return bytepos;
            if (mask & 0xaaaa)   // v1
                return bytepos + 16;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

That full example [compiles on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1AB9U8lJL6yAngGVG6AMKpaAVxYM9DgDJ4GmADl3ACNMYhAAZlIAB1QFQlsGZzcPPVj4mwFffyCWUPCoy0xrRKECJmICZPdPLgtMK0yGMoqCbMCQsMiLcsrq1LqFXra/DryuiIBKC1RXYmR2DgBSACYIv2Q3LABqJYjHPBYWPwJiPwA6BD3sJY0AQVX1hk3XHb3HIfxBS%2Bvbh/uhsRXNZtsRDMBMLsAOwAIT%2B222JwAHMYCNtMAA3RjGADWmAAnqRtscGESWExVHs4fcllCACJUv5/QHAtEYsFGSG06l3BGmFhcFZIvDorEMXEEsl%2BBREjkQ%2BgMRk0%2BlK/53AD06u2QyYNmQiIYtFGzNOrO27PBkPJeOMFs5EBZILlkOIkyZsL%2Bmu20WImB9qAWCniRm2RG2wFQ2wA7oQENtZsRQZaALTIBDFHHw7WmkF2iHm4iqhHs84khS7CJ0vlHYxKAhcYx%2BvBIiCg0t%2BbbJ7YaVRIjRuiI84vEc7OhUVqvGGt1htNltt8mqTvbCAjknJnt9ybbAdDgvnTHYvH4ifbKcsWuYeuN6LN1sjw/i487ougq9zBgF1W0hk0%2B78wVhXjdB0AUYxZgIcCqGMZ0IAAoURUfGUzynQCRQwUCiUdNlnQLN1lT3eCgIxBRXGCU9z1rMibzvDDkJLMtdyzIj0JA8DXFOS0KJrZAWGiYBILnCASLIokSzHRgmPuBEvRIA1cL2KteP4ghV0tBUxNI4JtwASVDBA/BxIl%2BETQwDReeIsSTTk9gAMSZaSUIFBDzUfKddTTbiL2UzAAEcaJbJCxIfMUJXxKTeQRbYvWCJh0HjQ0TzwKhRUYYkPPTeLVgANmA%2BLUBS51mNQlzYqyyszxrQx0FrPBAOEtzyQINMiQw9jOM5CKEV9AgP22MrvxVP87hY7Y0wzGDLQUOCSqAoKnLQvLkOwgsuIAKjzTBkJObYGHwh4PUcmStWiTAGm2XVtnoJghn0yEaGIW7CDCXVEm1SMFFQNhrPzLFrBIctRE/HUks/X1gDwIYwgULM%2BVmkV/WCegWHLRSlvaqDJvtea6OCqalgAVhhDRCbpLqoq9cl8VCb0ztoC7Q1Qcp6YK7YVnjRMIlh6KtR0lL/EDBQKkJMbfV1SF0HcFgTyYZAFmiAhk0PYh8QIAyQ2dcsO1EJRdorRxti54aou2EyVx2kU0a4CsYURd5PypO2VjhZ23UOyKTYW0q4tPOiMYKrGIQgHGQPozXCZhPBSfJz3EeR1GKsokhavquPMBRokyt3Y6Lrl9xXAMAhIVl4g4nLY91SKo7oV/NUTZ6vq05Rwba7%2BHaaAYGqHqGf3oNgtAGCewQUTRNboiwvAAC9MFRK7GCJAfbpW3C1oUUQDGIQOtqJHaGFdd09wRZKVz3itsG2LgNH7N9euIT9kxWR2eYuoMwjRBgmcZyNyQYE9NdNuSTBtgADVvB1yiitTaq1OQwyJnvUmr4ERmwgBbU8GgbZ232KfR2UdnarBhNubk3MTabVgZHUmp5rQz02g6deFQt5kKjgTMmiCa7cy9KdYgCAmDRHLAgVAkM0Rq0ht6X0/pBZ%2BGAPGDi8YUrCPLFQVwzwmh2Qch7ABiYHRTxnmiYIqs/RxDQRgvRRd0jvHHI7ExBiYZ4MrBEFYbtD6e1GhidBaNKK0FQHFVwKchRQEXmiFia03QrGytECOVizHO27NHVhJsXHW3cTWTx3jfEtggAEr2wpgk5XCUTSJcR8FcGyrEwcajPYUy1AoaIRohGRjouqJCCUFiykwK4YMUi1ZbWLsgUuQZiQFxsDUyEbljytTYrhaITA8CPWIVFUaTSkkXiRg4DEAU4LTloEaGixThJ1G2EiaY5oNBEkojOHZ2UIA9ivlQKgkwY7OPhktBESzjArM7msoSGJ9lnOINspsuzXFEkOac6cV5Zy3l2dcjQtz7lxPmU8puCclLpmQDiBhwcxTIVxtAiEyE94PJNko%2BIwB/DxXJAoHEXkpyoCxBS9FQkkWEqisfCA9LCHuwqRU1l9LdihO7KoAmQqCbbhzq4uZXKooNzvv1fRZiynV0lTym6VKcoCqYBqpgorn7fIlZKm%2BfUCmo2icU%2BFLyhrqJ/NzaV98uAtw4NMWgnACa8E8BwLQpBUCcANp9OYCw%2BURB4KQAgmgHXTBxJEAAnOcbKEQkRcAJlCJEkbJBQgiNlJEBN9CcEkLwFgEgr6kDdR6r1HBeAKBACckN7qHWkDgLAJAaA%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%2BCofXhh6QO3sMqHUHe/DvmwTRDC06iLrroucAnRxEbaJWZzYS5sRbxTlvoIgM4ZtXaA25fyzWwrEaVhpaa5IONBNI2ccjYKIUbXbudc4N1qtBXHWcBWEjktKPevA%2BmFiR6MnJBAA%3D), but untested other than that.  It assumes you have an even number of input vectors to process, although you can use `v1 = v0` for a left over solo vector.

It does use memory-source operands for some things, but unfortunately with an indexed addressing mode instead of iterating a pointer.  So it'll unlaminate to 2 uops on Sandybridge-family Intel CPUs.

---

SSE4.2 string instructions (like `pcmpestrm`) can do multiple range checks, but I don't think they can do it per-element-conditionally on another element.  They cost multiple uops (especially the explicit-length versions which are usable with `0` bytes in the data), so probably aren't useful.

In a slightly different case, like if every pair of bytes had to match one of the ranges, you could maybe use `pcmpestrm` or `pcmpestri` in 16-bit-element mode, with multiple range-checks.  e.g.  checking for the range 0x0201-0x0205, or the range 0x0304-0x0306 for each 16-bit chunk, and check that every word was part of a range.  (You'd need to byte-reverse within 16-bit elements, using `pshufb`).

@aqrit posted & deleted an answer attempting that.  If they get their idea working and undelete, see their answer.  I thought it was interesting enough to be worth a mention as a related case that may not quite work for this one.  I think it doesn't work here because the input vector can have an even byte that doesn't match any of the "keys".

Perhaps another `pcmpestrm` can make a mask of which 8-bit elements match one of the keys, using it's EQUAL_ANY mode.  And you can intersect that with another `pcmpestrm` 16-bit Ranges check which checks each element for being in one of the input ranges.  So if an even byte matched any key, the 16-bit element it's part of must be in one of the ranges.

See https://www.strchr.com/strcmp_and_strlen_using_sse_4.2 for some human-readable description of what the instructions can do, less opaque than the formal documentation.

Comment: `pcmpistrm` could match bad ranges, since there are only 3 bad ranges in the question. However, it is a bit silly.

Comment: @aqrit: The OP commented that "In this specific case, there are about 10 restrictions", so could well be worth it despite the 9 uop cost of `pcmpestrm` on Intel CPUs, with 5c throughput.  Or only 7 uops on Zen with 3 cycle throughput.  (`pcmpistrm` is much less bad, only 3 uops all for the same port on Intel, but it stops on `0` terminators which might occur in the data.  Maybe worth checking that there aren't any and branching?)